# Setting a global var for $(this) for separate jquery functions

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm using jquery for a cross browser solution for an input placeholder but I don't understand how to set a global variable for `$(this)` so that I can use it in the second part of this two part function. I first grab the value of the input and store it as `$value` but I need to use it again in the second function to replace the empty value with it. How do I do this? Something I should have mentioned is this needs to work for multiple text inputs in one form.

```
       $(document).ready( function() {
        $('input[type=text]')
         .on('focus', function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var $value = $(this).val();
            globalVar = $value;
            if($this.val() == $value){
             $this.val('');
            }
         })
         .on('blur', function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.val() == ''){
             $this.val($value);
            }
         });
       });
```

Comment: https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder/blob/master/jquery.placeholder.js

Comment: Why do you need a global variable, at first?

Comment: I have there text inputs that start with a value. I use the function to empty that value when that input is clicked and replace it the default value if nothing is entered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use a variable outside the scope of those two functions.. but it would probably better to use the `data` as a storage place:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        $('input[type=text]')
         .on('focus', function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.val()) {
              $this.data('myval', $this.val());
            }
            $this.val('');
         })
         .on('blur', function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.val() == ''){
             $this.val($this.data('myval'));
            }
         });
});
```

#### Edit:

added this:

```
   if ($this.val()) {
     $this.data('myval', $this.val());
   }
```

Comment: +1. Storing the data against the field one way or another is the only sensible thing to do here, and using `.data()` makes this easy.

Comment: I forgot to mention I was using multiple text inputs so this was the only option that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: A problem with this. I have 3 inputs. If I focus on one and then switch to another tab in my browser and comeback and blur that input...the value doesn't come back.

Comment: check if val is empty before setting it maybe: `if ($this.val()) { $this.data('myval', $this.val()); }`

Comment: I don't follow I thought we are doing that already with `if($this.val() == ''){`. Does the data get lost when browser tabs are switched?

Comment: the code would go in the focus section, so it doesn't store an empty value; i'll just update the full code above

Answer (score 2):

You must declare `$value` outside both functions, using a so-called *closure*. That way, $value is shared between both functions created within the same call of `ready`. (Remark: Since `ready` will most probably be called only once, you could also use a global variable. This, however, may pollute the global namespace, so I would rather not do it.)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        var $value;
        $('input[type=text]')
         .on('focus', function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $value = $(this).val();
            globalVar = $value;
            if($this.val() == $value){
             $this.val('');
            }
         })
         .on('blur', function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.val() == ''){
             $this.val($value);
            }
         });
       });
```

Note that this will not (or only by chance) produce the correct result if there is more than one `'input[type=text]` element, as all these elements will then share the same `$value` variable. In this case, you should use the `this.data` solution mentioned in the other posts.

Comment: What does the ready handler being called only once have to do with it?

Comment: Each call of the function given in the ready handler will produce a new $value. If it's called only once, there will be only one $value, thus you could as well use a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var $value;
$(document).ready( function() {
        $('input[type=text]')
         .on('focus', function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $value = $(this).val();
            globalVar = $value;
            if($this.val() == $value){
             $this.val('');
            }
         })
         .on('blur', function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.val() == ''){
             $this.val($value);
            }
         });
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable outside the function and then assign the desired value to it.

```
var $value = null;
$(document).ready( function() {
        $('input[type=text]')
         .on('focus', function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $value = $(this).val();
            globalVar = $value;
            if($this.val() == $value){
             $this.val('');
            }
         })
         .on('blur', function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.val() == ''){
             $this.val($value);
            }
         });
       });
```